# Login ASP.Net Identity 3.0 user to Identity 2.0 and generate JWT token

Tags: asp.net-identity, owin, jwt, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-identity-3

I am building a website using MVC 6 with ASP.Net Identity 3.0. But the API of the website was built in Identity 2.0.

To connect with Web API I need to get the JWT token from API.

Here comes the issues is, the OAuth provider in Web API authenticates the users created with Identity 2.0 but not the users created with Identity 3.0.

It seems both uses different hash mechanisms.

Could any one suggest me the best way to login Identity 3.0 user with Identity 2.0 context?

Thanks in advance.